# Remove Json Key in type script

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have the following JSON

```
var myObj = {'test' : {'key1' : 'value', 'key2': 'value'} , 'test2' {'key3':'value'} }
```

i need to remove **test** , **test2** key to be the following JSON

```
 [{'key1' : 'value', 'key2': 'value'} , {'key3':'value'}]
```

how can i do that in angularjs 2 ?
Thanks Advance .

Comment: There's no such thing as AngularJS 2, it's Angular. This is not JSON. This is plain object.

Comment: What's this got to do with typescript?

Comment: `Object.values(myObj)` Use this.

Answer (score 3):

> Your expected output is invalid JavaScript.

Perhaps you are willing to have an array of objects. You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) for this:

```js
let myObj = {'test': {'key1': 'value', 'key2': 'value'}, 'test2': {'key3':'value'}};

let result = Object.values(myObj);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert a js object to an array (without keys - `key1` and `test2`), you can use `Object.values`

You can use keys `0`, `1` ... in an array.

```js
var myObj = {'test' : {'key1' : 'value', 'key2': 'value'}, 'test2': {'key3':'value'} };
var myArr = Object.values(myObj);
 
console.log( myArr );
```

Doc: [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate it via keys

```
var myObj = {'test' : {'key1' : 'value', 'key2': 'value'} , 'test2': {'key3':'value'} };

var final = [];

for(var x in myObj){
  final.push(myObj[x]);
}
console.log(final);
```